# How to optimize .bashrc?

Tags: bash

I've been defining some functions in `.bashrc`, and now the start-up time isn't great.

I've tried a quick solution - to move the function definitions to `.bash_profile`, and export them, so they only get read once when I login. This makes sense, since these functions never change.

This works for tty logins, but not for the graphical environment. My system is Ubuntu 12.10.
I've googled that for the graphical session, the equivalent to `.bash_profile` is `.profile`.
The problem is that it's not equivalent:

```
export -f my_function
```

will work for `.bash_profile`, but not for `.profile`, because `.profile` is read by
`/bin/sh` and not `/bin/bash`.

So the last step to solve my problem would be one of:

1. Move function exports to `~/.profile-that-is-read-by-bash`
2. Make `/bin/bash` read `~/.profile`

Any ideas on this?

Comment: Call me ignorant, but I'm surprised that a bunch of function definitions would lead to a significant slowdown. How large are they? Have you considered locating where the actual bottlenecks are and optimise those instead?

Comment: @ShawnChin: A slowdown is about a second. But it's the difference between no perceptible startup time and perceptible startup time when I do Ctrl-Alt-T.

Answer (score 0):

The `tty` GUI sessions are probably not login shells, only interactive login shells read ~/.bash_profile or ~/.profile.  Bash reads ~/.profile (by default) only if ~/.bash_profile does not exist.

Exporting functions might be the overhead.  Do you really need all those functions every time?  Why not put them into some other file and `source` them when needed?

Comment: What I'm trying to do is eliminate the overhead: instead of sourcing the functions(which I need always) each time I open the terminal, just source them once at login, and have all new terminals inherit them(at no overhead).

Comment: There is still the overhead of maintaining the function code in the environment block if you export them.

Comment: If bash is written by any kind of sane person, and I'm sure it is, there's no such overhead. It's like in a dynamic language: when a function call is encountered, the name is looked up in local frame, if not found, then in parent frame etc. There's almost no overhead on this.